# Normals not baking as expected

Tags: normals, baking, error

I am working with 2.79.5 and a Bevel node from this version.

I use the bevel node to bake fake bevels on a normal map, bu the baking didn't turn out as expected, I ended up with a messed up normal map that doesn't even have bevels on the edges

Here is my result :
[image]

Here is a normal map made with another Object 
and the same method that turned out well :
[image]

and Here is my node setup (images textures being other shading maps) :
[image]

I still don't know why my normal map turned out so bad.
I also tried baking with high poly object and "Selected to Active" checked in the baking panel, but the result was the exact same. This kind of error happened only with a particular object that's on my model. Also made a quick try with 2.8, same result.

Comment: if it’s only one object that’s having issues then it’s likely something specific to that - eg, negative scale or flipped normals.

Comment: I checked, there is no flipped normals and the scale is 1

Comment: Smooth shading?

Comment: the smooth shading is applied as well, the only sharp edges are for the bevel to recognize them